# fixing child layout/widget position in QT

Tags: qt

I wanted to know whether is there any way of fixing child layouts within a parent layout. For example...

```
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
// adding pushbuttons/layouts...
vbox->addWidget(one);
vbox->addWidget(two);
vbox->addWidget(three);
vbox->addWidget(four);
```

Now this ends up as four buttons/layouts in a vertical layout in the sequence that they are added. But if I remove buttons/layouts "one", "two" and "three"...

```
vbox->removeWidget(one);
vbox->removeWidget(two);
vbox->removeWidget(three);
```

After doing this, the pushbutton "four" will move up the layout as you remove widgets on top of "four". I don't want this to happen.

Is there any way that even if I remove the widget/layout on top, I need that last widget/layout to stay where it is currently.
How do I achieve this ?

UPDATE: Well I was experimenting and I was *kind of* able to achieve what I wanted using QGridLayout. Here is the code, but I am using QGridLayout instead of QVBoxLayout.

```
connect(one,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(remove_btns()));

g = new QGridLayout(this);
g->addWidget(one,0,0,1,2);
g->addWidget(two,1,0,1,2);
g->addWidget(three,2,0,1,2);
g->addWidget(four,3,0,1,2,Qt::AlignBottom);
setLayout(g);
```

If I delete the above three buttons, the fourth one stays where it is, because of *QT::AlignBottom* , it does not work without that thing.
Here is the SLOT remove_btns()

```
void test::remove_btns()
{
    g->removeWidget(one);
    g->removeWidget(two);
    g->removeWidget(three);
    delete one;
    delete two;
    delete three;
}
```

When I click "one", top three buttons vanish, and the fourth one stays where it is. But it does not work if I don't give the *QT::AlignBottom* . Also, these *alignment* things are a mystery to me, I am unable to find how exactly they work.

This is definitely *NOT* an answer..., because I don't understand how it worked :P

Answer (score 2):

If you are immediately replacing the widgets you removed, you can always insert your new widgets by index.

```
void insertWidget ( int index, QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just hide the widgets instead of removing them:

```
one->hide();
two->hide();
three->hide();
```

If you really have to remove the widgets, perhaps you can replace them with some lightweight widget like a `QLabel` with no text.

Comment: Actually I want the previous widgets to be replaced by new ones, so will I be able to display new ones by hiding previous ones ? Anyway, the hidden objects will keep memory occupied, I don't want that.

Comment: @aditya - Use a QStackedLayout or QStackedWidget. As long as they have the same size and you add the new one before you remove the old one you shouldn't have any problems doing it that way.

Comment: Ok. I have never used this Stacked Widget since I am new to this, so I will give it a try. Thanks.